# How to get a property from a list by a property?

Tags: c#, list

I have a class:

```
public class Server
{
    public string ServerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a `List<Server>` and want to get the property "status" for a given ServerID.

How?

Comment: See http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Linq:

```
string GetServerStatus(string id)
{
    var server = servers.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServerId == id);
    if (server != null)
        return server.Status;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Server serverById=servers.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ServerId=="1");
if(serverById!=null)
  {
       MessageBox.Show(serverById.Status);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GetStatus(string serverID, List<Server> collection)
{
    string result = string.Empty;

    foreach(Server server in collection)
    {
         if (server.ServerID == serverID)
         {
             result = server.Status;
             break;
         }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Server FindServerByID(List<Server> list, string id)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
         if (item[i].ServerID == id)
              return item;
     return null;
}

public string GetStatusForServerByID(List<Server> list, string id)
{
     var server = GetServerByID(list, id);
     return server == null
          ? null
          : server.Status;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a from clause (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383978.aspx):

```
List<Server> yourlist = new List<Server>()
var data = from x in yourlist where x.ServerId == "1" select x.Status;
```